# using angularjs and nodejs in the .ejs file

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to Angularjs and want to know can we use angularjs in .ejs files for writing client side applications. Also, can we write both angularjs and nodejs files in the same .ejs file? I will be grateful for any further guidance.

Comment: Seems you are new to nodejs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to render the index page from server and then use angularjs local routing to load templates.